# Error when trying to acces parent TabNavigator's state inside child TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am currently trying to access the Parent Tab Navigator's state inside child Tab Navigator in the react-navigation while integrating redux into the app as well. But I am getting an error while trying to achieve the same.

Its said in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux) that

> Once you do this, your navigation state is stored within your redux store, at which point you can fire navigation actions using your redux dispatch function.
>
> Keep in mind that when a navigator is given a navigation prop, it relinquishes control of its internal state. That means you are now responsible for persisting its state, handling any deep linking, Handling the Hardware Back Button in Android, etc.
>
> Navigation state is automatically passed down from one navigator to another when you nest them. Note that in order for a child navigator to receive the state from a parent navigator, it should be defined as a screen.

So the docs tell us that the state is passed down. So technically I should be able to access them in the childNavigator. But for some reason, I end up in an error.

This is my rootNavigator:

```
class RootTab extends Component {
    render() {
        const { dispatch, rootNavigationState } = this.props;
        return (
            <RootTabConfiguration
                rootNavigation={
                    addNavigationHelpers({
                        dispatch,
                        rootState: rootNavigationState,
                    })
                }
            />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        rootNavigationState: state.rootTabState,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RootTab);
```

This is my Child Navigator:

```
class HomeTab extends Component {

    render() {
        const { dispatch, homeNavigationState } = this.props;
        const { rootState } = this.props.rootNavigation; //This line causes the error
        return (
            <HomeTabConfiguration
                homeNavigation={
                    addNavigationHelpers({
                        dispatch,
                        homeState: homeNavigationState,
                        rootState
                    })
                }
            />
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        homeNavigationState: state.homeTabState,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeTab);
```

This is the error I get:

[image]
I think I am understanding something wrong. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: form where rootNavigationState comes ??

Comment: its attached to redux